# Can't check if tab exists

Tags: c, tabs

I want to check if the `tab[i][j + 1]` exist, it is a  `int **tab;`

```
if (tab[i][j + 1] && tab[i][j + 1] == a_value)
    tab[i][j + 1] = 1;
printf("%d\n", tab[i][j + 1]);
```

and it print me `a_value` but if I take off `tab[i][j + 1]`

```
if (/*tab[i][j + 1] && */tab[i][j + 1] == a_value)
        tab[i][j + 1] = 1;
    printf("%d\n", tab[i][j + 1]);
```

it print me `1`.

Why can't I check if `tab[i][j + 1]` exist?

here is where I put the map in the array

```
while (tmp != 22)
    {
      ln = read(fd, buff, 22);
      buff[ln] = '\0';
      while (buff[k] != '\0')
        {
          if (buff[k] == 'x')
            tab[i][j] = WALL;
          else if (buff[k] == ' ')
            tab[i][j] = 0;
          else if (buff[k] == 'e')
            tab[i][j] = ENTRE;
          else if (buff[k] == 's')
            tab[i][j] = SORTIE;
          k++;
          j++;
        }
      k = 0;
      tab[i][j] = -5;
      j = 0;
      i++;
      tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(*tab) * 2000);
      tmp++;
    }
```

and here is the map

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxx                 s
xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxx           x
xx  xxxxx x   xxxxx x
xx xxxxxx xxx xxxxx x
xx        xxx xxxxx x
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxx x
xxxxxx        xxxxx x
xxxxxxxxx xxx   xxx x
xxx        xxxx xxx x
xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxx x
xxxxx xxx  xxxx xxx x
xxx   xxxx xxxx  xx x
xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx x
xxxx xxx   xxxxx xx x
xxxx     xxx      xxx
xxxxxxxxexxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: well you have a char str[3] if you do if (str[4]) it will check if str[4] is malloc (exist) but it do not work with int

Comment: @leykan Can you cite a reference where it says that? In my experience C doesn't do any bounds-checking so 'it' *won't* check if `str[4]` exists. Accessing elements that are not allocated is *undefined behaviour*

Comment: Such a check simply doesn't exist in general. It works for strings because there is a `0` added to the end. And ot works **only** if you check `str[strlen(str)]` not for indexes greater than `strlen(str)`

Comment: Where do you create `tab[][]` and define its size?

Comment: well because i do an open on a file to get a map

Comment: Can you include the code where you create the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As there are plenty of answers explaining the contradiction in your `if` I'll skip that.)

You can't check if `tab[i][j + 1]` exists because C doesn't maintain information about the size of (`malloc`ed) pointers (well, except the pointer-size, I'm talking about the size of the buffer following that pointer). If `tab` were a proper array you could use `sizeof` to check if the index if less than that. But as you declared `tab` as an `int **` this information is lost.

In short: you need to record the dimensions of `tab` somewhere or declare it as an array, for example:

```
int tab[4][5];
```

You could then use something like this to check if a certain index in the array is in-bounds:

```
#define isAllocated(array, index) (index < sizeof(array))
```

and use it like:

```
if(isAllocated(tab[i], j+1) && tab[i][j + 1] == 0){ ...
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `tab[i][j + 1] && tab[i][j + 1] == 0` is equivalent to `tab[i][j + 1]!=0 && tab[i][j + 1] == 0` which is impossible, hence resolves to false (0).

Why is it equivalent to this? Because a statement `if(someStmt)` is equivalent to `if(someStmt!=0)`, because in C any number different than zero is assumed `true` and zero is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because condition `tab[i][j + 1] && tab[i][j + 1] == 0` will always be `false`. At a time `tab[i][j + 1]` will either contain a non-zero value or a zero value.

Comment: no tab[i][j + 1] == 0 because it print 0 but i how cuold i check if tab[i][j + 1] exsit because i will segfault if i look at tab[i][j + 1] if it do not exsit

Comment: What do you mean by `exist`?

Comment: i have int tab[3] but if i look at tab[4] i segfault so how could i check if it exsit

Comment: Where do you define the size of `tab[]`?

Comment: because with char *str when you do if (str[i]) it will check if str[i] exsist

Answer (score 1):

considering `tab[i][j+1]` is `0`

```
if (tab[i][j + 1] && tab[i][j + 1] == 0) will result in if(0 && 1)/if(false && true) == if (0)/if(false)
```

Hence assignment statement `tab[i][j + 1] = 1;`  doesn't execute and `tab[i][j+1]` value printed = `0` (that I am assuming)

```
if (/*tab[i][j + 1] && */tab[i][j + 1] == 0) will result in if(1)/if(true)
```

So  assignment statement `tab[i][j + 1] = 1;`  executes and outputs `1`.

Comment: Why should we consider `tab[i][j+1]` is `0`?

Comment: @nhgrif I think what AJ means to say that `if (tab[i][j + 1] && tab[i][j + 1] == 0)` always evaluates to False.

Comment: `if(tab[i][j+1] && tab[i][j+1]==0)` always evals `false`, but `if(tab[i][j+1]==0)` doesn't always evaluate to `true` (or `false`).  This answer should be edited to show checking zero and non-zero in the first `if` to demonstrate its always falseness.  Moreover `if(1)` or `if(0 && 1)` probably is only useful to someone who already understands the problem with the first `if` statement.  And as such, should probably be clarified as `if(true)` and `if(false && true)`.

Comment: @nhgrif IF I read AJ answer again I think his guess is correct.

Comment: @AJ. You should improve answer.

Comment: Moreover, Igor Popov's answer is a better way of saying exactly what @GrijeshChauhan seems to think AJ is saying here.

Comment: @nhgrif yes  Igor Popov's answer explain better.